# Set UL as dropdown on mobile and full width on desktop

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

**Background**

We have the following code to have a horizontal `<ul>` that we want to take up the full width of the `<div class="list__wrapper">` element on desktop (`min-width: 1024px`), but display as a dropdown for mobile breakpoint (`max-width: 1024px`).

**Code**

- Link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/userrj/pen/PXYmRj)

**Issues**

1. Make all `<li>` elements take up full width (currently there is some space left on `desktop` and `mobile`).
2. As the `<div class="list__wrapper">` expands, then the `<li>` take up the whole space available. Currently it does not even if change the `max-width: 50%` on the `.list__wrapper` class.

**Current output**

1. `desktop`
   [image: current output desktop]
2. `mobile (not expanded)`
   [image: current issue mobile (not expanded)]
3. `mobile (expanded)`
   [image: Current Issue mobile (expanded)]

**Desired output**

1. `desktop`
   [image: desired output]
2. `mobile (not expanded)`
   [image: desired mobile (not expanded)]
3. `mobile (expanded)`

[image: Desired mobile output (expanded)]

**Code:**

```js
var wind = $(window);
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
wind.on('resize load', function() {


    if (windowWidth < 1024) {
        $("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
            $(this).parent().children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
        });

        var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
        $("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
            allOptions.removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
            allOptions.toggle();
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.list__wrapper {
  max-width: 50%;
  background-color: grey;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  ul { 
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  li.init { 
    cursor: pointer; 
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    
  }
  .list li {
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list__wrapper">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="init">Option 0</li>
        <li data-value="value 1">Option 1</li>
        <li data-value="value 2">Option 2</li>
        <li data-value="value 3">Option 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ul` has default margin and padding values. i reset the values and delete the `max-width`.

```js
var wind = $(window);
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
wind.on('resize load', function() {


    if (windowWidth < 1024) {
        $("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
            $(this).parent().children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
        });

        var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
        $("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
            allOptions.removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
            allOptions.toggle();
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.list__wrapper {
  background-color: grey;
}

ul {
  padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .list__wrapper {
  background-color: grey;
}
  ul { 
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
  }
  li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  li.init { 
    cursor: pointer; 
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    
  }
  .list li {
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list__wrapper">
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="init">Option 0</li>
        <li data-value="value 1">Option 1</li>
        <li data-value="value 2">Option 2</li>
        <li data-value="value 3">Option 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this helped solved my issue with minimal changes to the html structure :-)

Answer (score 0):

1.Make all `<li>` elements take up full width (currently there is some space left on desktop and mobile).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  ul { 
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100vw; // vertical width of screen
  }
  li {
    width: 100%; 
  }
  li.init { 
    cursor: pointer; 
  }
}
```

2.As the `<div class="list__wrapper">` expands, then the `<li>` take up the whole space available. Currently it does not even if change the max-width: 50% on the .list__wrapper class.

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
      .list {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex: 1;
        align-items: center;

      }
      .list li {
        padding: 10px;
        color: white;
        flex:0 0 25%; // use flex sizing for flexboxes
        //flex:grow(1/0) shrink(1/0) width;
        text-align: center;
        border-left: 1px solid white;
      }
    }
```